# Youtube App on iPhone ignoring private videos

Tags: iphone, safari, uiwebview, youtube, uiapplication

I seem to have noticed an odd bug in the YouTube App with the iPhone. I have written a small program that fires off the YouTube app with a url like:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adsakasjda

This video is a private video held on youtube. When the Youtube player launches I receive the message "YouTube not available". HOWEVER, I am logged in as the owner of this private video. With this in mind I DONT QUIT THE YOUTUBE APP but instead, after dismissing the error I navigate to "My Videos" using the tab at the bottom. Low and behold I can view the video correctly.

I am wondering if this is something similar to cross site scripting.... since Im sending a URL OVER the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];  method, perhaps the Youtube App is resigned to rejecting it first. However, this doesnt figure as NON private videos work fine.

I have tried the UIWebView approach. Once the user has signed in, firing requests almost works but the embedded youtube objects have the struckout play button over them and they wont load up when clicked.

GData offers no solutions as one can't simply view a private page with a security token. This has been a feature request for some time now.

Comment: Oh yes, the youtube link in there is meant to be fake ;)

Comment: You are the owner of the video, as in it was you that posted it and made it private? Or the Youtube app logs you in as the owner, even though you actually aren't??

Comment: Apologies, yes, I am the Owner and I have set up the YouTube App with the credentials of the owner. If you fire up the Youtube App directly you can see the owner's videos fine. If you fire a link from another app into the YouTube App it fails

Comment: I'm seriously considering this to be a bug with the YouTube App. Best to check first though

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Youtube App bug, because I just tested with a Private Video I do not own, but I have access to on the Mac via Safari. My Youtube App is connected onto my Youtube account, but I still get the "Youtube not available" message for that video if I try to open it via url through Mail App. Public videos work fine.